# Change huge amount of data from NIST to RIFF wav file

Tags: audio, wav, sox

So, I am writing a speech recognition program. To do that I downloaded 400MB of data from TIMIT. When I inteded to read the wav files (I tried two libraries) as follow:

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile
import wave

(fs, x) = wavfile.read('../data/TIMIT/TRAIN/DR1/FCJF0/SA1.WAV')
w = wave.open('../data/TIMIT/TRAIN/DR1/FCJF0/SA1.WAV')
```

In both cases they have the problem that the wav file format says 'NIST' and it must be in 'RIFF' format. (Something about sph also I readed but the nist file I donwloaded are .wav, not .sph).

I downloaded then SOX from http://sox.sourceforge.net/
I added the path correctly to my enviromental variables so that my cmd recognize sox. But I can't really find how to use it correctly.

What I need now is a script or something to make sox change EVERY wav file format from NIST to RIFF under certain folder and subfolder.

EDIT:
in [reading a WAV file from TIMIT database in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44748258/reading-a-wav-file-from-timit-database-in-python?rq=1) I found a response that worked for me...
Running `sph2pipe -f wav input.wav output.wav`
What I need is a script or something that searches under a folder, all subfolders that contain a .wav file to apply that line of code.

Comment: Try sox recital.nist recital.riff

Comment: sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `recital.nist': No such file or directory

Comment: Instead of 'recital' you need to put your file name

Comment: ahaha sorry. Worked perfectly, just a code of sox SA1.WAV SA1.WAV! It's actually better because I can rewrite the file. The other solution can't (at least for me). THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I got it finally. Go to the upper folder and run this code:

```
forfiles /s /m *.wav /c "cmd /c sph2pipe -f wav @file @fnameRIFF.wav"
```

This code searches for every file and make it readble for the python libs. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 7):

Since `forfiles` is a Windows command, here is a solution for unix.
Just `cd` to the upper folder and type:

`find . -name '*.WAV' | parallel -P20 sox {} '{.}.wav'`

You need to have installed *parallel* and *sox* though, but for Mac you can get both via `brew install`. Hope this helps.