# TIMIT Corpus. Cant play .WAV audiofile but can play it if I convert it into .mp3

Tags: mp3, media-player, speech-recognition, wav

I downloaded the files from the timit speech corpus found here: https://github.com/philipperemy/timit

When I try playing the .WAV files with groove music or windows media player I get an error saying the file cannot be played.

However after converting the file to mp3 using an online converter, the file suddenly works.

The .WAV files are only around 100-200KB in size.

Does anyone know what the reason for this problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: [reading a WAV file from TIMIT database in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44748258/reading-a-wav-file-from-timit-database-in-python)

Apparently it is not actually a .WAV file but a NIST file.